# How to use String Interpolation for YouTube video

Tags: java, android

I need to put my variable **youTubeLink** inside of a new video url object for **src**. How can I insert the variable here? I tried wrapping it in String.format and it threw an error.

```
youtubeVideos.add( new YouTubeVideos("<iframe width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" src= \"youTubeLink(THIS IS THE SPOT)\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>") );

// Returns an error saying cannot resolve method format (boolean, Java.lang.String)
String.format(youtubeVideos.add( new YouTubeVideos("<iframe width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" src= \"%s\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>") ), youTubeLink);
```

Comment: What error? Please show the code you tried

Comment: Added it. Thank you

Comment: Have you looked at the method definition or examples of `String.format`? `youtubeVideos.add` doesn't return a String

Comment: I figured String.format wouldn't work. I was hoping there would be a better solution for interpolation in the Java world.

Comment: Well, you could also do addition `"iframe" + value + ">"`

Comment: Ahhh yes! That's what I'll do! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You only need to format the string, not the entire method call.

Try starting like this

```
youtubeVideos.add( new YouTubeVideos(
    String.format("%s", value)
);
```

Note: you'll need to HTML encode your value string

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error because you are trying to put result of `youtubeVideos.add` which is Boolean method to `String.format`

You may want to use StringBuilder to properly set your String with proper link

```
"<iframe width=\"100%\" height=\"100%\" src= \"youTubeLink\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>"
```